# Is there any way to programatically download a youtube video in mp4 format?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I own a YouTube channel with 500+ videos. I create one to two videos a week. I am building my own website where I want to host these videos as well.

To quickly move all my older videos I want to create a script where for a given YouTube video URL the video is downloaded in MP4 format. I can then tie this into a larger workflow which leverages Youtube and Akamai's APIs to move videos from Youtube to Akamai automatically.

I know how to use YouTube's APIs to get all my video URLs. I do not want to embed a Youtube video and need to (for business reasons) use a service like Akamai.

I want a solution I can automate so not looking for apps that do this.

Comment: When I click download it gives me a URL like `https://youtube.com/download_my_video?v=VIDEO_ID&t=TOKEN`. Maybe this is what you're looking for?